# How to install Twig 2.x in Phalcon 3.2.4

Tags: php, twig, phalcon

I am working on a newly created `Phalcon` project, and I don't really know how to install `Twig` 2.x in my `Phalcon` 3.2.4 project.

I have tried to install `Twig` via composer and then follow these steps: http://www.calinrada.com/using-twig-with-phalcon-php/ - But it doesn't work.

Also tried this: https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/450288/USING-TWIG-WITH-PHALCON (With `Twig` as `git` submodule and `Incubator` has `git` submodule too but it does not work).

is there a fresh guide to do this?

I really like `Volt`, but it does not support for embedding blocks into other blocks (Please see: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/329).

Comment: It does not work is not a really precise description. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @entio, Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Twig_Autoloader' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the incubator to load twig or mustache

```
composer require phalcon/incubator
composer require twig/twig
composer require mustache/mustache
```

And then when your register your view service:

```
$view = new View();
$view->setViewsDir($config->application->viewsDir);
$view->registerEngines(array(
     '.phtml' => 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Php',
     '.volt' => 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt',
     '.mustache' => 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Mustache',
     '.twig' => 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Twig',
));
```

Comment: What is Mustache?

Comment: Mustache is a template engine like volt or twig but it's also support many programming language https://mustache.github.io/ https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php